# Replace main scroll bar with (bootstrap) modal's one

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap modal, and when I open it, the window's scroll bar disappears and the modal has its own scroll bar. I'd like to shift modal's scroll bar to the very right, so have it in the place of the window's one and not at the right of the modal's div!

In the image below you can see an example of that.

[Example of what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsYDI.png)

Could anyone help me to make it!?

Comment: This is helps you : https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/javascript/scroll/

Comment: Nope, that doesn't help me!

Comment: Please add your html and css code to make  a [minimal_example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)